# How to show perfect completeness of the Set Lower Bound Protocol?

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

In [these lecture notes](https://theory.epfl.ch/courses/complexity/Lecture8.pdf) (on page 5 under "Some Remarks") it is claimed that the Set Lower Bound Protocol (given there on page 4) can be modified to have perfect completeness. However, while I understand why the original protocol works I do not see how such a modification is possible. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: It's not necessarily easy. If you're curious, I suggesting searching the literature for the original paper.